# Updating a Bar Chart with PythonPPTX

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm trying to update an existing bar chart in a powerpoint deck with just one value and keep getting this error message: "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable" when I try to add the data series. There is another bar chart on this slide that has 2 values in the data series and that one works perfectly fine. Anyone know how to update a bar chart with just the one data point?

```
chart3=slide_8.shapes[22].chart
chart3=CategoryChartData()
chart3.data.categories=["TV"]
chart3.data.add_series=("Frequency",(slide_8_data.loc["TV Frequency"]["Value"]))
chart3.replace_data(chart3_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The value provided as the second parameter to `.add_series()` needs to be an iterable, meaning something like a list or tuple. If you instead provide a scalar value, like a number on its own (not inside a list), then you get the error you mention. In the general case, the values for a series are a *sequence*. So if it's only a single value, it needs to be a *list* (or *tuple* or 1D *ndarray*, or possibly an *iterator*) containing that single value.

If the parentheses surrounding `slide_8_data.loc[...` are meant to make it into a tuple, you need a comma at the end (a special case for single-value tuples in Python). `(42,)` is a tuple containing the single value `42`. `(42)` is just `42` with parentheses around it for no particularly useful reason (there's no operator precedence grouping to be done).

Comment: Thank you so much!! So how exactly would you change this line of  code so it would work?
    chart3.data.add_series=("Frequency",(slide_8_data.loc["TV Frequency"]["Value"]))

Comment: You can make it work for the offending case with: `chart3.data.add_series=("Frequency",(slide_8_data.loc["TV Frequency"]["Value"],))` (note the comma near the end) but that's going to break it elsewhere if `slide_8_data.loc["TV Frequency"]["Value"]` sometimes resolves to a scalar and other times to an array. In that case you'd need some conditional logic, perhaps in a separate function, to deal with the two cases and wrap a scalar value in a list or tuple when that happens.

Comment: btw, Welcome to StackOverflow :)  Don't neglect to accept the answer that best responds to your question. That's how we say thanks here on SO :)